# On-select event not being triggered with RactiveJS

Tags: javascript, ractivejs

Am I doing something wrong?

My template

```
   <select id="muni" class="form-control" value="{{formData.muni_ssn}}" on-select="muni_selected">
       {{#formData.municipalities}}
       <option value="{{ssn}}">{{name}}</option>
       {{/formData.municipalities}}
   </select>
```

My js code

```
var caseForm = new Ractive({
    el: "case-form",
    template: "#CaseFormTemplate",
    data: {
        formData: mappeal.caseFormData
    }
});

caseForm.on("muni_selected", function (event) {
   alert(event.context.formData.muni_ssn);
});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's no such thing as the `select` event. In standard JavaScript, without Ractive, you'd do this to listen to changes in the `<select>` element's value:

```
// 'change' event, not 'select' event
document.getElementById( 'muni' ).addEventListener( 'change', function () {
  console.log( 'select value changed to', this.value );
});
```

So the equivalent in Ractive would be

```
<select id="muni" class="form-control" value="{{formData.muni_ssn}}" on-change="muni_selected">
  {{#formData.municipalities}}
    <option value="{{ssn}}">{{name}}</option>
  {{/formData.municipalities}}
</select>
```

But there's actually a slightly easier way to listen for those changes with Ractive - observe the data itself. First, we can get rid of the event handler directive:

```
<select id="muni" class="form-control" value="{{formData.muni_ssn}}">
  {{#formData.municipalities}}
    <option value="{{ssn}}">{{name}}</option>
  {{/formData.municipalities}}
</select>
```

Then, in your code, do this:

```
caseForm.observe( 'formData.muni_ssn', function ( newValue, oldValue ) {
  console.log( 'changed from', oldValue, 'to', newValue );
});
```

The advantage of doing it this way is that you don't need to distinguish between changes that happen as a result of DOM interaction, and changes that happen programmatically (e.g. as part of your initial setup) - making it much easier to keep track of application state.

Comment: Using observe is much better!